# How to make a base class for ReactJS classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would I make a base class for my ReactJS components where I'd encapsulate some common behavior for all of the descendants.

Right now I have at least 3 classes that have a common method functionality

```
  handleClick: function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    this.props.onClick(this.props.value);
  },
```

which is copy/pasted. :(((

Coming from the C#, where I'd split everything into smallest possible pieces, this really bugs me.

Ideally I'd like to have such a method in base class

```
  handleClick: function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    onClick(); // this method would be virtual in base class and overridden in children classes
  },
```

Is it possible to achieve this in ReactJS? Or what would be another best approach for such functionality in ReactJS or JavaScript world?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [React Mixins](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins).

This would allow you to define the function centrally and just *mixin* where you need it.

```
var HandleClickMixin = {
  handleClick: function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    this.props.onClick(this.props.value);
  }
};
```

Which can then be used:

```
var SomeReactComponent = React.createClass({
  mixins: [HandleClickMixin],
  render: function() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Click Me.
      </button>
    );
  }
});
```

You still need to provide the *onClick* and *value* props, but otherwise it's a one line addition.

Comment: but this doesn't solve the situation when we have 10 buttons on same control that needs this behavior.

Comment: How doesn't it? Or rather, what code would you be duplicating?

Comment: no, the code doesn't duplicate and I really like the idea with mixins, but in this case I cannot have 10 buttons with different click handler, at least I don't know how to make each button to have a different `this.props.onClick` but same 2 line of code for prevent bubbling.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, you would make a class to wrap the button, so make the _SomeReactComponent_ class above something like: `var ButtonNoBubble = ... mixins: [HandleClickMixin] ... return (<button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.text}</button>);` Which would then be used on some other component that manages the form: `var FormManager = ... return (<ButtonNoBubble onClick={this.clickHandlerA} text="Button A" value={this.values.A} /><ButtonNoBubble onClick={this.clickHandlerB} text="Button B" value={this.values.B} /> ... );` You could also change that to use _this.props.children_

Comment: Here's some more information on the subject that may be useful in general: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html

Answer (score 1):

In ReactJS world, it's generally preferred to use **composition** patterns over classical inheritance.

In your case, you could use the **higher-order component** pattern (very well explained in [this post by Dan Abramov](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.6n2i3tkix)) like this:

```
// higher-order component creator:
function getClickHandlerComponent(OriginalComponent) {

    const ClickHandlerComponent = React.createClass({
        handleClick: function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
            this.props.onClick(this.props.value);
        },
        render: function() {
            return (
                <OriginalComponent
                    {...this.props}
                    handleClick={this.handleClick}
                />
            );
        },
    });

    return ClickHandlerComponent;  // higher-order component (HOC)
}

// Used like this:
const SomeButton = getClickHandlerComponent(React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        // original props,
        handleClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,  // added by the HOC
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <input
                type="button"
                value="Click me"
                onClick={this.props.handleClick}
            />
        );
    },
}));
```

The functionality which is provided by the higher-order component (here, the "handleClick" handler) can be added to any component that needs it: the component simply receives it in its props.

Answer (score 0):

I would think of it more like a utility function that handles clicks, thats said, 
there are a number of ways to do this. Lets say we have a utility function(s) in a file called utils.js:

```
// utils.js
export function someUtilityFunction (a) {
  return axios.all(players.map(function (username) {
    return getUserInfo(username)
  }))
  .then(function (info) {
    return info.map(function (user) {
      return user.data
    })
  })
  .catch(function (err) {console.warn('Error in func: ', err)})
};


Then in another file, lets say Main.js:

// Main.js
import { someUtilityFunction } from from '../utils/';

// someUtilityFunction is now available in this file
```

Note the export and import keywords.

Above I am using ES6 syntax, which needs to be transpiled down to ES5 for the browser (I use babel.js);

Take a look at these docs to see variations of this in both ES5 and ES6:

[MDN docs on export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

Comment: Would you mind to create a small JSBin sample of it. Little confused, how to use the exported function as a method of another class.

Comment: you would just add it as a method, and bind it in the constructor, see here: https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus in the arrow functions part, its not exactly the same but should show you...

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways

ES6 Classes: If you're using ES6 classes you can create a base class that `extends Component` from `react` and then extend your components from this base class

Context: If you take a look at `react-router` you can get more implementation details but in short, `context` is shared by all children and grandchildren so you could make your base component and then pass down methods to the children.

Comment: can't use ES6 yet, but I'll check about the `context`. Thx

Comment: It's not a stable feature but I'm sure there'll be a solution if they ever remove it